# Is a Δ-Y conversion a must?

Tags: power, circuit-analysis

Can the equivalent impedance be solved without Delta to Wye transformation?

[image]

Comment: this question makes no sense. You can analyze any circuit with universal methods (as, for example, used in computational network analysis). That conversion is just easy and helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Mesh Analysis

Re-drawn, you can see that there are 5 mesh analysis loop currents:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVwEPO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you use mesh analysis then set \$V_1=1\:\text{V}\$ and solve for the unknown loop currents. The resistance is \$R_\text{TOTAL}=\frac{V_1=1\:\text{V}}{I_{\text{L}_1}}\$.

### Nodal Analysis

You can see that there are 9 unknown voltage nodes for nodal analysis.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ft5lK2.png)</sup>

If you use nodal analysis then set \$I_1=1\:\text{A}\$ and solve for the unknown node voltages. The resistance is \$R_\text{TOTAL}=\frac{V_{\text{N}_1}}{I_1=1\:\text{A}}\$.

### Combo Approach

It just crossed my mind that you could try a further simplification prior to analysis in order to reduce the number of simultaneous equations to solve.

If you look at the nodal analysis schematic above, you can see some simplifications:

1. Remove \$R_2\$ and \$R_6\$ (short them out.) These are "series resistances" that can be added back after additional analysis, since they are in series with the remaining circuit.
2. Apply a Norton to Thevenin conversion of \$I_1\$ in parallel with \$R_8\$.

You now have the following simplified schematic that can be solved using mesh analysis with 4 loops instead of 5.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foxIZK.png)</sup>

Here, you'd compute \$R_\text{MESH}=\frac{V_\text{TH}=1.2\:\text{kV}}{I_{\text{L}_1}}\$. Once you solve that, you can then add back the values of series resistors, \$R_2\$ and \$R_6\$, and that should be the same as the computed results from the earlier two examples, as well. In short, \$R_\text{TOTAL}=R_\text{MESH}+R_2+R_6\$.

Comment: This is the same principle we use to find Thévenin/Norton equivalent resistance/impedance when there are dependent sources.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use either node or mesh analysis method to solve this problem without using the delta-wye conversion.

Or you could use node or mesh analysis to find the equivalent resistance of the part of the network containing deltas, and then use parallel and series combinations to find the equivalent resistance of the whole network.